# Facebook request

Tags: php, facebook

I have a cool canvas application on Facebook, and sometimes there appear some cool news, some of them are really important, and i wanna notify users of my application about the news by request. 
I just wanna them see some numbers of request from my application with a shortcut to my application on their page.

How can i do it in php without any js ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Request `publish_stream` access permissions and your app can post to the user's wall using Graph API's /me/feed.  There's lots of examples of how to HTTP Post.